# how to retrive image from database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, blob

I tried using this code to retrieve the image from database which is stored in `blob` format
but this method does not work and my application crashes whenever this method is called 
so how can I retrieve my image in byte or bitmap format from the database.
because I want to use that `imageswitcher`

My logcat shows

```
07-26 18:12:51.253: E/string1(15682): --Hatheesingh jain temple
07-26 18:12:51.844: E/SQLiteLog(15682): (1) near "jain": syntax error
07-26 18:12:51.884: E/AndroidRuntime(15682): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 18:12:51.884: E/AndroidRuntime(15682): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.starting.starting/com.starting.starting.detailpage}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "jain": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM database WHERE place_name =Hatheesingh jain temple
07-26 18:12:51.884: E/AndroidRuntime(15682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-26 18:12:51.884: E/AndroidRuntime(15682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
```

```
public byte[] get_image(String str){

    //openDataBase();


   Cursor c1 = checkDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM database WHERE place_name =" +str, null);
    byte[] img = c1.getBlob(10);
   return img;
    //CloseDataBase();

   }
```

Comment: DATABASE  is reserved word and also post logcat exception.

Comment: What does LogCat says ?

Comment: Does your `database` have 11 columns? Post the `CREATE` statement

Comment: image is stored in 11 column and database is my table name

Comment: @nikhil There can be many reasons - post LOGCAT man if you want us to look into it.

Comment: It might be best to avoid using `database` as a table name. It's a reserved word in many database systems. Avoid names like `table` or `database` and try to thing of a word which described what the rows in the table actually represent in your domain.

Comment: (My initial guess would be that you need quotes around the string, e.g. `Cursor c1 = checkDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM database WHERE place_name = '" + str + "'", null);`), but that rather depends on what `str` is. Also, as others have said, logcat output is there for a reason: if your app is crashing, post the exception details and things will become a lot clearer.

Comment: Did you try `moveToFirst()` on your cursor ? What's the exception ?

Comment: i have added logcat plese refer to it

Comment: @nikhil : I have pointed out the mistake and answered your question. Check my Answer below and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your LogCat, it's SQL syntax error in your Query. You haven't wrapped the the string in single quotes so it is SQL Compile error, as clearly mentioned in LogCat

**Change**

```
   Cursor c1 = checkDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM database WHERE place_name =" +str, null);
```

**To**

```
Cursor c1 = checkDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM database WHERE place_name ='" + str + "'", null);
```

Besides this, also call `c1.moveToFirst()` to avoid `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

`database` is a reserved keyword in SQLite. **You can not use it as a table name**

Look at this [SQLite reserved keywords](http://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Also you need to call

```
c1.moveToFirst();
```

before

```
byte[] img = c1.getBlob(10);
```

or else you will get an `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`.